# How can I use the default my.cnf template for the mysql chef cookbook?

Tags: mysql, vagrant, chef-infra

I have been trying to get my head around the changes in the chef mysql cookbook (https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql) between version 5.x and version 6.x, and I am struggling a little bit.

I have it successfully installing, but I don't understand how to use the default my.cnf template provided by the cookbook. Because it's in a different cookbook, my database recipe can't find it. I tried copying it to my cookbook, but when I do that the @config variable is not initialized, so it has a fatal error.

Here's what my database recipe looks like at the moment (basically the example provided in the README):

```
mysql_service 'default' do
  port '3306'
  version '5.5'
  initial_root_password 'change me'
  action [:create, :start]
end

mysql_config 'default' do
  source 'my.cnf.erb'
  notifies :restart, 'mysql_service[default]'
  action :create
end
```

Following the suggestions in the replies, I now have this for my mysql_config:

```
mysql_config 'default' do
  source 'my.cnf.erb'
  cookbook 'mysql'
  variables :config => {
              :name => "mysql",
              :port => 3306,
              :user => "mysql"
            },
            :pid_file => "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid",
            :socket_file => "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock",
            :include_dir => "/etc/mysql/conf.d/"
  notifies :restart, 'mysql_service[default]'
  action :create
end
```

which returns this error:

```
Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (undefined method `name' for {:name=>"mysql", :port=>3306, :user=>"mysql"}:Hash) on line #1:

  1: # Chef generated my.cnf for instance mysql-<%= @config.name %>
  2:
  3: [client]
  4: <% if @config.charset %>
  5: default-character-set          = <%= @config.charset %>
```

I also placed my cookbooks for this minimal example up in github: https://github.com/rhuffstedtler/chef-mysql-database-example

Comment: I just noticed this issue: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/issues/302. I haven't had a chance to work from the example the issue submitter included, but I suspect it might help a lot.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Haven't really had a reason to circle back around to it - we changed our default VM to one provisioned with ansible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change the my.cnf, but you have to pass the variables to mysql_service and you don't have to use mysql_config. (See below)

After having the same problems I found this in the mysql cookbook folder mysql/libraris/rsource_mysql_sercie.rb

```
require 'chef/resource/lwrp_base'

class Chef
  class Resource
    class MysqlService < Chef::Resource::LWRPBase
      self.resource_name = :mysql_service
      actions :create, :delete, :start, :stop, :restart, :reload
      default_action :create

      attribute :charset, kind_of: String, default: 'utf8'
      attribute :data_dir, kind_of: String, default: nil
      attribute :initial_root_password, kind_of: String, default: 'ilikerandompasswords'
      attribute :instance, kind_of: String, name_attribute: true
      attribute :package_action, kind_of: Symbol, default: :install
      attribute :package_name, kind_of: String, default: nil
      attribute :package_version, kind_of: String, default: nil
      attribute :bind_address, kind_of: String, default: nil
      attribute :port, kind_of: String, default: '3306'
      attribute :run_group, kind_of: String, default: 'mysql'
      attribute :run_user, kind_of: String, default: 'mysql'
      attribute :socket, kind_of: String, default: nil
      attribute :version, kind_of: String, default: nil
    end
  end
end
```

-> So if you want to change things in the instance/my.cnf file, you have to use the parameters of the mysql_service definition for example like this:

```
mysql_service 'default' do
  version '5.5'
  port '3306'
  socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
  initial_root_password "#{node['mysql']['server_root_password']}"
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers, Roger

Comment: I was able to test it today and after uninstalling mysql and rerunning chef cookbook mysql it worked. socket and pid file were stored at the new location, in my case /run/mysqld instead of /run/mysql-default/

Comment: Thanks, @rroger - I'll see if I can give it a try this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

The `template` resource has an attribute `cookbook` which tells it which cookbook to look in.  As for the `@config` being initialized, it is also your responsibility to pass that value into the `mysql_config` resource. Furthermore, if you look at the template, it requires a few other variables too.  Several of those variables are optional, as you can see from the template code.  So you'll want something like this:

```
mysql_config 'default' do
  source 'my.cnf.erb'
  cookbook 'mysql'
  variables :config => <some config hash>,
            :pid_file => <your pid file path>,
            :socket_file => <which socket to use>,
            .....
            :temp_dir => <you get the idea>
  notifies :restart, 'mysql_service[default]'
  action :create
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Tejay. That found the template, but the @config object isn't being populated. 

Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass) on line #1:

  1: # Chef generated my.cnf for instance mysql-<%= @config.name %>
  2:
  3: [client]
  4: <% if @config.charset %>
  5: default-character-set          = <%= @config.charset %>

  (erubis):1:in `block in evaluate'

I pushed an update to the github project if you'd like to see what I currently have

Comment: Updated my answer to cover the cause of your `@config` issue too.

Comment: Thanks, Tejay. I think that's getting me closer, but for some reason it wants to treate name on my config hash as an object method rather than a field in the hash. I updated my answer above (and my code repo)